# select each table column using javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, iterator, selector

Identify each column of a “div > span” table using javascript returning an array with each column.
[image]

**[fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/A2M22/619/)**

I have no clue how to do that, if someone can help me with this :|

I have tried something with `document.querySelectorAll("")` but I don't know how to iterate from top to bottom ...

Answer (score 1):

You want this ? Open Example in Full Page

```js
var temp = -1;
var arr = [];

$('span').on('click', function(){
   
  if(temp !== -1){
    $('div.row span:nth-child(' + (temp + 1) + ')').css({'color': 'black', 'font-weight': 'normal'});  
  }

  var index = $(this).index();
  arr = $('div.row span:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').css({'color': 'red', 'font-weight': 'bold'});
  temp = index;
  
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(arr, x => console.log(x));
})
```

```css
.table {
    display:table;
    border: 3px solid #555;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.row {
    display:table-row;
}

.rowGroup {
    display:table-row-group;
}

.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    width:2%;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table">
   <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="cell cas4">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
       <span class="cell">X</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
       <span class="cell">X</span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
       <span class="cell">X</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
       <span class="cell">X</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
       <span class="cell">X</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
       <span class="cell">X</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
       <span class="cell">X</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
       <span class="cell">X</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rowGroup">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
      <span class="cell">X</span>
       <span class="cell">X</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactlly this scenario, thank you for your effort but i need native javascript :|